# Multi-Session Variables in MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access, persistence

Is there a way to store variables in access which retain their data even after access restarts? The idea is that I will log the date and time of when the form was last opened, which will allow me to only show records since it was last opened.

Comment: Any reason why you do not wish to use a table?

Comment: @Remou I would happily, I'm just not too sure how to go about it. How would I set and get the variables?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338978/ms-access-what-is-a-recordset-in-vba-what-does-it-serve for some ideas. You can also update a table with a query or an sql statement.

Comment: @Remou Thanks. In the meantime, I found this tutorial: http://accessexperts.net/blog/2011/01/12/multi-session-global-variables/ but I'm getting a 'Run time error: 3021 - Either BOF or EOF is true, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record'.

Comment: Never-mind, I had to add one record manually before it worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are inside Access, just create a table to store such information!

Comment: Sort of like a 'Settings' table? I'm not that familiar with access, what code would I use to get and set the data in the table?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes looking here for a method to store Permanent Variables (aka Multi-session Variables) without using Access tables. Here is the techique to achieve this.

> Crux : Use `TextBox` `DefautlValue` to store data.

```
Dim strForm As String
Dim frm As Form
strForm = "FormName"
DoCmd.OpenForm strForm, acDesign, , , , acHidden
Set frm = Forms(strForm)
frm.Text0.Caption = "Test"
frm.Text0.DefaultValue = 4
Set frm = Nothing
DoCmd.Close acForm, strForm, acSaveYes
```

Important Note : Form needs to be open in Design view.