# Running an update query to a memo field

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

This may be a simple one (whether it is possible or not)..   I have two tables which are identical with a set of records.  I need to find the best way  that when one of the memo fields is modified, that the modifications get carried to the identical record on the corrisponding identical table.  In many cases the field may have hundreds of words..   The only way that i know how to potentially do this is using an update query, but i am wondering if the test within is really large, will it break?  Or is there another way?  Thanks, A

Comment: Is the update within a form? Why do you have two identical memo fields?

Comment: it should be within the form..   They are identical because basically one table i use as a working table and it is compiled form a bunch of underlying tables which feed to it.  This table was created specifically for a report but now i want the user to be able to change the content of one memo field within the report and i would like thta this change gets reflected in the underlying table

Comment: Odd. Consider the AfterUpdate event with a suitable ID.

Comment: Yes, but do you see any disadvantage to using an update query (in SQL), linking the two records and updating the memo field??

Comment: Sorry, you have to excuse my ignorance.. Are you refering to using something along the lines of DAO or ADOX?

Comment: DAO more or less every time with MS Access http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338978/what-is-a-recordset-in-vba-what-purpose-does-it-serve/2339004#2339004

Answer (score 2):

Since you're working with Access 2010 you can use an After Update data macro to copy the changes back to the main table:

[image: AfterUpdate.png]

For more information see

[Create a data macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx)