# Updating a memo field in a table with text in a text box

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to update the memo field 'Note' in table 'tblDependencies01' with the text entered on a form in text box 'txtInfo'. I am getting the following error message:

impossible to refer to a property or a method for a control that does not have an active status

I am not sure what this means.   Below is my code:

```
Private Sub Comando105_Click()

Dim sql_get As String

sql_get = "UPDATE tblDependencies01 SET Note = " & txtInfo & " WHERE ID=" & txtDependencyID
CurrentDb.Execute sql_get

End Sub
```

Comment: Note http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21893437/running-an-update-query-to-a-memo-field?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

.Text property is not available unless the control has focus. Use .value, if you are determined to have a property, or just skip properties because .value is the default.

You are looking at a world of hurt when you use sql to update a loaded form.

Comment: Fionnuala, i tried your suggestion but still get a syntax error message. The code is updated above

Comment: You have not quoted a text data type, AFAICT, you will need to escape any contained quotes. The way you are going not a good way to update.

Comment: Fionnuala, i edited the code as you are suggesting but am still getting the same error message. Sorry

Comment: Please post your revised code. Please eliminate the line `Me.txtInfo.SetFocus`. Please use `CurrentDb.Execute sql_get` rather than `Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (sql_get)` Please consider another method altogether.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still have the same issue.  I am sorry but another method does not come to mind.

Comment: I cannot understand why you are getting the same error message. Can you ensure that you have posted the revised error message and that you have stepped though the code to get the line on which the error occurs.

Comment: The error is an error with Syntax (run time 3144). The line highlighted is CurrentDb.Execute sql_get

Comment: So NOT the same error. Try running the query in the query design window. Make sure you add the quotes that I suggested you added here: `SET Note = """ & txtInfo & """ WHERE ID`